# C++ - Would like some help on this sorting code

Tags: c++, sorting, integer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int val1;
int val2;
int val3;
int sortArray[3];

int main(){

    printf("Enter three integer values.\n");
    printf("Please enter integer 1: ");
    cin >> val1;
    printf("Please enter integer 2: ");
    cin >> val2;
    printf("Please enter integer 3: ");
    cin >> val3;


    //Checks val1 status
    if (val1 > val2, val3) {
        sortArray[1] = val1;
    }
    if (val1 > val2, val1 < val3){
        sortArray[1] = val3;
        sortArray[2] = val1;
        sortArray[3] = val2;
    }
    if (val1 > val3, val1 < val2){
        sortArray[1] = val2;
        sortArray[2] = val1;
        sortArray[3] = val3;
    }

    //checks val2 status
    if (val2 > val1, val3){
        sortArray[1] = val2;
    }
    if (val2 > val1, val2 < val3){
        sortArray[1] = val3;
        sortArray[2] = val2;
        sortArray[3] = val1;
    }
    if (val2 > val3, val2 < val1){
        sortArray[1] = val1;
        sortArray[2] = val2;
        sortArray[3] = val3;
    }

    //checks val3 status
    if (val3 > val1, val2){
        sortArray[1] = val3;
    }
    if (val3 > val1, val3 < val2){
        sortArray[1] = val2;
        sortArray[2] = val3;
        sortArray[3] = val1;
    }
    if (val3 > val2, val3 < val1){
        sortArray[1] = val1;
        sortArray[2] = val3;
        sortArray[3] = val2;
    }

    printf("Values sorted are: %d, %d, %d", sortArray[1], sortArray[2], sortArray[3]);
}
```

This program works when the values are input in the following orders:

1, 2, 3

1, 3, 2

3, 1, 2

but does not work with:

2, 3, 1

3, 2, 1

2, 1, 3

Any Ideas what im doing wrong here? Id love some help as this has been irking me for a while now.

Comment: `if (val1 > val2, val1 < val3){` does most likely not do what you think it does. Enable more compiler warnings.

Comment: The problem is that you are randomly inventing syntax then wondering why it doesn't work as you expect... Where did you read that you could write things like `if (val1 > val2, val3)`?

Comment: Go look up conditional statements. Also, Id recommend: The C++ Programming Language by Bjarne Stroustrup

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be a little confused on how if statements work in C++. If you want multiple conditions that all have to be true in order to execute the code, you need to use &&, not a comma. Commas do something different, they execute several statements but only use the last one for evaluation. [Read this article](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/), particularly the sections titled "Logical Operators" and "Comma Operator".

In summary, for every one of those if statements replace the comma with &&. That, however, does not address the fact that your sorting algorithm is not very scalable, since you've hardcoded every possible scenario. Look up some real [sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

Comment: Ahh okay thank you. Ill make sure to try that. Im following a book, and it told me to just Use If statements. (since we have not gotten to the && operator I tried using without)

Answer (score 0):

you are using comma like Jordan said, and arrays start with index 0 in C++. Then if you declare an array with size of 3, its first value will be array[0] and its final one is array[2]

for sorting try this:

```
   int sortArray[3];
    sortArray[0] = 3;
    sortArray[1] = 2;
    sortArray[2] = 1;

    //sort ascending 
    //double check
    for( int i = 0; i< 3 ; i++)
    {
        for( int j = 2/*size -1*/; j > 0 ; j--)
        {
            if (sortArray[j-1] > sortArray[j])
            {
                int temp = sortArray[j];
                sortArray[j] = sortArray[j-1];
                sortArray[j-1] = temp;
            }

        }
    }

      //  printf("Values sorted are: %d, %d, %d\n", sortArray[0], sortArray[1], sortArray[2]);
//use cout to print 
cout <<"Values sorted are: "<<sortArray[0]<< sortArray[1]<< sortArray[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

you should replace `,` with `&&` in your conditional statements.
i.e.,

```
if (val1 > val2 && val3) {
```

Notice that there are many ways to sort like: Quicksort, ‎Merge sort, Insertion sort, ‎Heapsort and bubble sort. You can find samples of them in c++ for practice.

Also there is a built-in library [`sort()`](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-c-stl/).